# Linking external svg file with its html code

Tags: html, css, svg

is it possible to link my svg file with my css file? I want to make a line animation with my svg file. I'm not sure whether its a good idea to put my svg code on my html file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want!

**img.html**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
.....
.....
</svg>
```

**style.css**

```
.div {
    background-image: url(img.html);
}
```

**test.html**

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: My svg file is external, and i want to be able to use it for a line animation, is that possible?